# s3fs: Could not load mime types for curl library

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, s3fs

I have a strange problem. Last thursday my code has worked, so I'm a little bit confused.

What I want: Mount an S3-Bukket via S3FS to an EC2-Instance.

What thursday worked: Successfully mounted that S3-Bucket to my EC2-Instance.

What today is not working: Mounting that S3-Bucket to my EC2-Instance.

My EC2 Userdata:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 yum install -y automake fuse fuse-devel gcc-c++ git libcurl-devel libxml2-devel make openssl-devel
 git clone https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse
 cd s3fs-fuse/
 ./autogen.sh
 ./configure --prefix=/usr --with-openssl
 make
 sudo make install
 mkdir -p /s3/mybucket
 s3fs -o iam_role="MYROLE" -o url="https://s3-eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" -o endpoint=eu-central-1 -o dbglevel=info -o allow_other -o use_cache=/tmp MYBUCKET /s3/mybucket
```

After I run the s3fs command its returning:

```
s3fs: Could not load mime types for curl library.
```

and the bucket wasn't mounted.

What I tried:

- yum update libcurl
- setting up s3fs on a different EC2 instance by hand. Also not working...
- checked my IAM Role (which worked last week and wasn't changed)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Welcome to the community Teapot! Could it be that it is failing because of the name? You might already have used that name and now when you are trying to do the same thing it is failing because the bucket name is already in use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install the mime types via: `yum install mailcap`.

Comment: I filed a bug to make this more obvious: https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse/issues/1270 .  Note that you should be able to dnf install s3fs-fuse which will take care of dependencies for you.